# Codeigniter, active record, join

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, activerecord, left-join

I am currently in the process of building a little game to learn myself some active record (codeigniter) and php. So I am fairly new to all of this.

And of course I've encountered the following challenge on the road.

The challenge is, I have two tables, **User_Heroes** and **Heroes**.
The table **Heroes** contains all the heroes a user can choose during his time playing a game (that belong to his faction) and **User_Heroes** is the table of heroes that the user has already recruited into his service.

The thing I want to do is as follows, I want to make a query that returns a list of heroes that the current user doesn't have in his employ.

To simply get them all I would do this

```
public function get_faction_heroes($sUser, $hero_faction){
        $oQuery = $this -> db
                        -> select(' id,
                                    hero_name,
                                    hero_faction,
                                    hero_type,
                                    hero_cost,
                                    hero_maintenance,
                                    hero_allowed')
                        -> like('hero_faction',$hero_faction)
                        -> get('heroes')
                        -> result();

        return $oQuery;
    }
```

Currently I have the following Query build up, but obviously it is wrong as it does not return the list as I expect it to return.

```
 public function get_faction_heroes($sUser, $hero_faction){
    $oQuery = $this -> db
                    -> select(' h.id,
                                h.hero_name,
                                h.hero_faction,
                                h.hero_type,
                                h.hero_cost,
                                h.hero_maintenance,
                                h.hero_allowed')
                    -> like('h.hero_faction',$hero_faction)
                    -> where_not_in('u.hero_id', $sUser)
                    -> where('h.hero_allowed >', 1)
                    -> join('user_heroes u', 'u.hero_id = h.id', 'left')
                    -> get('heroes h')
                    -> result();

    return $oQuery;
}
```

As you might notice, some heroes are allowed to be recruited multiple times (hero_allowed > 1).

Perhaps to further clear up the table I've added two images with the current tables

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think you should use right join (not left)

Comment: Already tried that, sadly it's not the sollution :(

Comment: use $this->db->last_query(); to getting last query fired after that you have to play with query in phpmyadmin or similar mysql application to get desired problem. Actually your problem is not releted to codeignter it's related to query.

Comment: For getting better solutions You can make sql fiddle which simulates the situation.

Comment: I know it's not codeigniter, I've just hit a wall in how to properly construct this query (be it in Active Record or just plain MYSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('Heroes');
$this->db->where('`id` NOT IN (SELECT `hero_id` FROM `User_Heroes`)', NULL, FALSE);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Oh that allmost does what I want, the only thing that I need to check now is if the hero in the list is allowed more than once.

Comment: Then you just add 1 more line after `where` condition which is like that `$this->db->where('Heros.is_allowed >','1')`

Comment: I'm gonne change the way it works, since a hero is a hero and there can be only one, a footman is just a grunt and you can have many more than just 5 or 6 etc. 

but thanks for you insight anyway :D